# cannot connect to mysql rds instance using .NET mysql connector

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-rds, tls1.2, mysql-connector

We need to enable TLS1.1 connections on mysql rds instance. I have a console application that I am using to test my connection to the mysql RDS instance.

After many to-and-fros with Infra team, it is confirmed that mysql instance is using TLSv1.1. Please find the command outputs that I have run in  the mysql workbench :

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`

[image]

- show global variables like '%ssl%'

[image]

Now this verifies that the server is using TLSv1.1.

---

**Connection establish efforts - Workbench**

Everything works fine

---

**Connection establish efforts - Using mysql.exe (server/bin/)**

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u serverusername -h xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com dbname -p --ssl-mode=PREFERRED`

Asks for password and connects fine 
[image]

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u serverusername -h xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com dbname-p --ssl-mode=DISABLED`

Asks for password and connects fine

### [image]

**So now we have sufficient facts to say that from this aws Vm we are able to connect to the RDS instance using workbench and mysql.exe utility (both SSL enabled)**

Then next we try to connect to the same RDS instance using a console application that is using the mysql connector DLL provided by the mysql team. Please find application code below along with mysql connector dll version

Code :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;



        Console.WriteLine("making certficate connection");

        string connMainOut = connMain();

        Console.WriteLine(connMainOut.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

 private static string connMain()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conns"]);
            connection.Open();
            return connection.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("==============================");
            Console.WriteLine("connMain" + ex.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("==============================");
            return "null";
        }
    }
```

**MySql connector version :**

[image]

My app.config looks like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="conns" value="SERVER=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;
database=databasename;
user=username;
PASSWORD=password;
SslMode=PREFERRED;"/>
      </appSettings>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
        </startup>
    </configuration>
```

It throws this error

[image]

Now with using SslMode=None;

[image]

Now with SslMode=REQUIRED , I get the same error

[image]

We have already spent a lot of time on this and still are unable to connect using TLS. If more information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error log it also says "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted" which generally means that something is wrongly configured on the server. TLS 1.1 is not considered secure anymore.

Download [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) to review “Schannel” and “Cipher Suites” tabs and see if settings are correctly configured and post making the changes can restart the server.

[More Reference](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/system-security-authentication-authenticationexception)

Comment: by "wrongly configured on the server" you mean to say that something is incorrectly setup on the RDS instance?  Also, we know that it is not secure anymore, but the problem is that I was getting the exact same errors when I tried connecting with the TLS1.2 but couldnt make it work, so we thought that maybe its happening due to the TLSv1.2. But I guess we are doing something incorrectly. All this being said, my major confusion is that if there is anything wrong with the RDS instance config, then how is mysql.exe able to connect to it without any warnings or errors.

Comment: SChannel is OS dependent and if incorrectly configured or configured to use only the latest TLS/SSL versions, may lead to problems with TLS/SSL negotiation. I am saying, please verify the settings mentioned in my last step of your VM not the RDS instance. RDS has just generated the SSL, .Net uses SChannel.dll as underlying SSL/TLS implementation

Comment: i will be updating what has helped me.  using best practices in the IIS Crypto was very very important. And we switched off some ciphers because some webapp scanning security tool raised the concern that those ciphers are not safe. It was really a stupid mistake \